# JPA named query using OR and Null Operator giving empty result

Tags: java, jpa

Written named query

```
  @NamedQuery(name = PKGruppeBE.FIND_ALL_GROUP_SPECIFIC, query = "SELECT e FROM PKGruppeBE e 
  WHERE 
  (e.tkgroup.id = ?1 OR e.tkgroup IS NULL )")
```

But query is not giving correct result,

if **there is a match**, and **tkgroup is null**  giving only matched results,

if **there is no match**, and **tkgroup is null** giving empty result.

My requirement is I have to get all results where **tkgroup is null** and if are there any matches those results also.

Comment: This was my exact scenario and @Predrag Maric's answer was spot-on... And it makes perfect sense when you look more closely at the query he provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try if this works

```
SELECT e FROM PKGruppeBE e left join e.tkgroup gr WHERE gr.id = ?1 OR gr IS NULL
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to left join, try my edited query. I just tried this in my project, and it works.